# Syntax error on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting red `X's` in my code for the closing `}` I have. They all look fine to me the IDE insists that I am wrong. I'm not sure why this is incorrect. Could someone guide me the way please thank you!

The errors occur at the last 2 closing `}`

## 1 error:

```
Syntax error on token "}", { expected after this 
 token
```

## 2 error:

```
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete 
 ClassBody
```

Here is my code

```
public class BinaryTree { 
    // root node pointer. Will be null for an empty tree
    private Node root;

    /*
     -- Node --
     The binary tree is built using this nested node class.
     Each node stores on data element, and has left and right 
     sub-tree pointer which may be null.
     The node is a "dumb" nested class -- we just use it for storage; 
     */

    private static class Node {     // Node class
        Node left;
        Node right;
        int data;

        Node(int newData) {         // create Node
            left = null;
            right = null;
            data = newData;
        }
    }

    /*
     Creates an empty binary tree == null root pointer
     */

    public void BinaryTree() {
        root = null;
    }

    /*
     Returns true if the given target is in the binary tree
     */

    public boolean lookup(int data) {       // look up a number 
        return(lookup(root, data));         // use this to parse through a tree to search for element
    }

    /*
     recursive lookup -- given a node, recur
     down searching for the given data.
     */
    private boolean lookup(Node node, int data) {
        if (node == null) {
            return(false);
        }

        if (data == node.data) {
            return(true);
        }
        else if (data < node.data) {
            return(lookup(node.left, data));
        }
        else {
            return(lookup(node.right, data));
        }
    }

    public void insert(int data) {
        root = insert(root, data);
    }

    /*
     Recursive insert -- given a pointer, recur down 
     and insert the given data into the tree. Returns the new 
     node pointer (the standard way to communicate 
     a changed pointer back to the caller).
     */

    private Node insert(Node node, int data) {
        if (node == null) {
            node = new Node(data);
        }
        else {
            if (data <= node.data) {
                node.left = insert(node.left, data);
            }
            else {
                node.right = insert(node.right, data);
            }
        }
    }    // I get an error here    #1

    return (node);
}        // I also get an error here   #2
```

Comment: `return (node);` is not within a method. It should probably be 2 lines higher...

Comment: please stop posting answers for such a trivial problem. I am sure OP could have answer his question by himself with some little help.

Comment: and usually eclipse wins..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change insert to :

```
  private Node insert(Node node, int data) {
            if (node == null) {
                node = new Node(data);
            }
            else {
                if (data <= node.data) {
                    node.left = insert(node.left, data);
                   }
                else {
                    node.right = insert(node.right, data);
                     }
                 }
                 return (node);
        }
```

In eclipse : Press Ctrl + a and then Ctrl+shift+f to format code.. you will get to know such errors easily...

Answer (score 0):

```
    private Node insert(Node node, int data) {
            if (node == null) {
                node = new Node(data);
            }
            else {
                if (data <= node.data) {
                    node.left = insert(node.left, data);
                }
                else {
                    node.right = insert(node.right, data);
                }
       -->      return (node);// I get an error here    #1
--->       }
```

You wrote return statement outside. I moved it inside. Please update.

Answer (score 0):

Error is because you have the following statement

```
return (node);
```

out of your `insert` method

Answer (score 0):

complete working code

```
public class BinaryTree { 
    // root node pointer. Will be null for an empty tree
    private Node root;

    /*
     -- Node --
     The binary tree is built using this nested node class.
     Each node stores on data element, and has left and right 
     sub-tree pointer which may be null.
     The node is a "dumb" nested class -- we just use it for storage; 
     */

    private static class Node {     // Node class
        Node left;
        Node right;
        int data;

        Node(int newData) {         // create Node
            left = null;
            right = null;
            data = newData;
        }
    }

    /*
     Creates an empty binary tree == null root pointer
     */

    public void BinaryTree() {
        root = null;
    }

    /*
     Returns true if the given target is in the binary tree
     */

    public boolean lookup(int data) {       // look up a number 
        return(lookup(root, data));         // use this to parse through a tree to search for element
    }

    /*
     recursive lookup -- given a node, recur
     down searching for the given data.
     */
    private boolean lookup(Node node, int data) {
        if (node == null) {
            return(false);
        }

        if (data == node.data) {
            return(true);
        }
        else if (data < node.data) {
            return(lookup(node.left, data));
        }
        else {
            return(lookup(node.right, data));
        }
    }

    public void insert(int data) {
        root = insert(root, data);
    }

    /*
     Recursive insert -- given a pointer, recur down 
     and insert the given data into the tree. Returns the new 
     node pointer (the standard way to communicate 
     a changed pointer back to the caller).
     */

    private Node insert(Node node, int data) {
        if (node == null) {
            node = new Node(data);
        }
        else {
            if (data <= node.data) {
                node.left = insert(node.left, data);
            }
            else {
                node.right = insert(node.right, data);
            }
        }
        // I get an error here    #1

    return (node);
}      }  //
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning at the end of the class outside of any method, which is an error.